# Using csv modele to extract specific lines of text from a larger file

Tags: python, csv

So I'm extracting the lines that I want from this larger file using this program:

```
import csv

name = ['NAMETHEFIRST,' 'NAMEANOTHERNAME ']
data = csv.reader(open('C:\\bigfile.csv'))

with open('C:\\smalldataset.xcl','w') as outf:
    csv.writer(outf).writerows(l for l in data if l[0] in name)
```

The program runs. However I am only getting the line of data from `NAMETHEFIRST` and I get no data from `NAMETHEOTHERNAME` written to my small dataset file. This works exactly as I want printing all relevant info from the large data set of the line of data for NAME THE FIRST but i get no information from the second nametheother name written to the smaller file. Why isn't this working?

Comment: You're talking about two files yet your code is clearly operates with a single file. Also, second element of the list `name` has space after it. Is this intentional?

Comment: @SilentGhost: (1) input-large file, (2) output-small file, `assert 1 + 1 == 2`

Comment: @SilentGhost: His list has only ONE element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list with one string:

```
['NAMETHEFIRST,' 'NAMEANOTHERNAME ']
```

This is a list with two strings:

```
['NAMETHEFIRST', 'NAMEANOTHERNAME ']
```

Note the placement of the comma.

Also note that your second string has a space at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code

```
name = ['NAMETHEFIRST,' 'NAMEANOTHERNAME ']
```

is equivalent to

```
name = ['NAMETHEFIRST,NAMEANOTHERNAME ']
```

because Python follows C in concatenating adjacent string constants at compile time.

You say """I am only getting the line of data from NAMETHEFIRST and I get no data from NAMETHEOTHERNAME written to my small dataset file""" -- however **the code that you show will NOT produce that result**; it will select only lines that start with

```
"NAMETHEFIRST,NAMEANOTHERNAME ",
```

You will get the stated result only if that line is actually:

```
name = ['NAMETHEFIRST', 'NAMEANOTHERNAME ']
```

and that is presumably because the second name in the file doesn't have a trailing space as above.

Other problems:

`csv.writer(outf).writerows(l for l in data if l[0] in name)` is trying to be a bit too clever. If you break it down into bite-size chunks, you can much more easily use a debugger or just print statements to show you what is actually happening.

Try this:

```
print len(name), name
data = csv.reader(open('C:\\bigfile.csv', 'rb')) # ALWAYS open csv files in BINARY mode
with open('C:\\smalldataset.xcl','wb') as outf: # ALWAYS open csv files in BINARY mode
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for row_index, row in enumerate (data): # don't use 'l' as a variable name
        print row_index + 1, row
        if row[0] in name:
            writer.writerow(row)
```